# document.execCommand() fontSize

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, contenteditable, execcommand

```
document.execCommand("fontSize", false, value);
```

i am getting the third parameter "value" from the user which is in "pixel".
but execCommand only allows the input between 1-7 that too in "point".
How should  I calculate the value?

Comment: 1pt is 1.3281px, if that's what you're asking for. You can't go above 7pt for some reason--that's just the limit. `document.execCommand` is obsolete anyway, if you want a rich text editor there are libraries out there.

Comment: Is it not possible without the library? I can't use any richText editor library for some reasons.

Comment: Why can't you use a library? `contenteditable` is not a good replacement for proper rich text editing.